# how to find bonded and free funds in a nomination pool account using Polkadot JS API?

Tags: polkadot-js

[image]

how to find bonded and free funds in a nomination pool account using Polkadot JS API? from https://staking.polkadot.network/#/pools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Free Funds**

```
api.query.system.account(accountAddress);
```

`free` depicts the free funds.
[image]

**Bonded Funds**

```
api.query.nominationPools.poolMembers
```

`points` depicts the bonded funds.
[image]

Can test it out at the [polkadot js developer dashboard](https://polkadot.js.org/apps)